# How to get the path of executed .jar file?

Tags: java, jar

How do I get the path of a an executed .jar file, in Java?

I tried using `System.getProperty("user.dir");` but this only gave me the current working directory which is wrong, I need the path to the directory, that the .jar file is located in, directly, not the "pwd".

Comment: From where? Inside the JAR file itself?

Comment: Yes, from code inside the JAR file itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you specify why you need the path?
If you need to access some property from the jar file you should have a look at ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
don't forget that your classes are not necessary store in a jar file.

```
// if your config.ini file is in the com package.
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("com/config.ini");
System.out.println("URL=" + url);

InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("com/config.ini");
try {
    if (is != null) {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("resource not found.");
    }
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

regards.

Comment: Need to get access to the config.ini file that is stored in the same directory as the .jar file.

Comment: Have a look at ClassLoader#getResource / #findResource.

Comment: not sure if it can work if the config file is external to the jar.

Comment: This only works if the resource is in your classpath. If not you, to know where it is located and create an InputStream to access its content.

Answer (score 0):

Taken From [Java-Forumns](http://www.java-forums.org/advanced-java/13329-obtaining-relative-path-outside-executable-jar.html):

```
        public static String getPathToJarfileDir(Object classToUse) {
        String url = classToUse.getClass().getResource("/" + classToUse.getClass().getName().replaceAll("\\.", "/") + ".class").toString();
        url = url.substring(4).replaceFirst("/[^/]+\\.jar!.*$", "/");
        try {
            File dir = new File(new URL(url).toURI());
            url = dir.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
            url = null;
        } catch (URISyntaxException ue) {
            url = null;
        }
        return url;
      }
```

Comment: This does not work, returns the path to the JRE when used as instructed. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps java.class.path property?

If you know the name of your jar file, and if it is in the class path, you can find its path there, eg. with a little regex.