# Integrating scipy with java

Tags: java, python, scipy

Is there now a simple way to pass Java classes to a .py program using scipy libraries?

I have seen suggestions for using Jython here on StackExchange ([Java Python Integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119696/java-python-integration) and [Using Python from within Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164810/using-python-from-within-java)). I have also seen posts saying that it will not work with numpy or similar libraries ([Integrate Python and his libraries with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32143032/integrate-python-and-his-libraries-with-java), [Calling python functions from *.py files from java and passing and returning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39470221/calling-python-functions-from-py-files-from-java-and-passing-and-returning), and [Executing Python script from Java in Tomcat project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530627/executing-python-script-from-java-in-tomcat-project)).

I would like to be able to pass a Java class to the .py code, run a scipy computation, and then pass the results back to Java (something that I am currently able to do with MATLAB .m files). I would also like to be able to put this on a parallel processing cloud server since 1) my real-time Java program (running the GUI and main features) is already on the cloud, and 2) computational speed is of essence.

Comment: MATLAB has been integrated with Java for quite sometime.  But `scipy` works with `numpy`, and uses a lot of compiled `C` code.  So it works best with the regular Python (`CPython`).  Adaptations to alternative Pythons (Jython, Ironpython, Pypy) are, at best, partial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing java-specific or java-aware in scipy.